# Adding and Editing using same connection in EF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4 to look up a item in the database, to determine if it needs to be inserted or edited like so:

```
 List<Campground> CampgroundEntities = new List<Campground>();

 using (MiscEntities pd = new MiscEntities())
            {
                Campground kc = pd.Campground.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);

                if (kc != null)
                {
                    kc.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
                    kc.City = city;
                    kc.State = state;
                    kc.Zip = zip;
                    kc.URL = campgroundUrl;
                    kc.UpdatedDT = DateTime.Now;

                    CampgroundEntities.Add(kc);
                }
                else
                {
                    kc = new Campground();
                    kc.Name = name;
                    kc.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
                    kc.City = city;
                    kc.State = state;
                    kc.Zip = zip;
                    kc.URL = campgroundUrl;
                    kc.AddedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                    CampgroundEntities.Add(kc);
                }
            }
```

I'm adding my entities to a list, then after that, I want to commit those changes to the database:

```
        using (MiscEntities pd = new MiscEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in CampgroundEntities)
            {
                pd.Campground.AddObject(item);
            }
            pd.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Now obviously that doesn't work, but if possible, I'd like to use that connection to handle both inserting and updating.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (MiscEntities pd = new MiscEntities())
{
    Campground kc = pd.Campground.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);

    if (kc == null)
    {
        kc = new Campground();
        pd.Campground.Add(kc);          
    }

    kc.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
    kc.City = city;
    kc.State = state;
    kc.Zip = zip;
    kc.URL = campgroundUrl;
    kc.UpdatedDT = DateTime.Now;

    CampgroundEntities.Add(kc);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says pd.Campground does not contain the .Add method.

Comment: pd.Campground must be an list and should have the add method.